Dash Python: @Callback in Layout function not being called
I have a simple dataframe:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'Class2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
)  

I have created a data extraction function that splits the data based on the position of the column.
data_extraction.py
def dataExtraction(arg1):

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Class1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                             'Class2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})  ## <-- or Import df from somewhere
    df = df[[f'Class{arg1}']]

    return df    

layout.py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
from dash import Dash, dash_table, State
import dash_daq as daq
import pandas as pd

def update_page(arg1, arg2):
    layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.H1(f'Class {arg1}'),
        daq.NumericInput(
            id='numericinput1',
            min=0,
            max=100,
            value=0, ), 
        html.Br(),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='tableTest',
            data=arg2.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in arg2.columns]),
    ])

    return layout

@callback(
    Output('tableTest', 'data'),
    Input('numericinput1', 'value'),
    State('tableTest', 'data'),
)

def updateTableTest(x,data):

    data = pd.DataFrame(data)

    if x > 0:
        **print(data) # Indicator that shows callback is working**
    print("CALLBACK WORKING!!!")

        return data.to_dict('records')
    return data.to_dict('records')


I have also constructed a tab page as follows that consists of a page with 2 tabs. The tab_page displays the tabs with their respective data column  (E.g. tab 1 for column 1). I have written 'print (data)' to check that the callback in the layout function is working. It is working for one tab but not the other.
tab_page.py
import layout as lay
import data_extraction as de
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, Dash
import dash

app = Dash()

dash.register_page(__name__, 
                   path='/tabs') 

def get_layout(position):
        df = de.dataExtraction(position)
        layout = lay.update_page(position, df)
        return layout


tab1_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
                **get_layout(1)#<--- CALLBACK NOT WORKING HERE The print(data) is NOT working**
        ]
    ),
    className="mt-1",
)

tab2_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
                get_layout(2) #<--- The print(data) is working
        ]
    ),
    className="mt-2",
)

layout = html.Div(children = [
    dbc.Tabs(
    [
        dbc.Tab(tab1_content, label="1",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),
        dbc.Tab(tab2_content, label="2",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),
    ]
)])


app.layout = [layout]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


The callback in the layout works for the get_layout(2) but not get_layout(1). Why does it work for one and not the other?

Hi, I have fixed several typos in the code (edited it inplace in the question) then tested your code and it works fine. When visiting http://127.0.0.1:8050/tabs I see two tables - one with Class1 and the other with Class2

Thank you for the editing, i am away from my editor and cannot access the link. But will this resolve the callback issue i have with get_layout(1)? . My original code did  display two tables but the callback was not working for get_layout(1) so print(data) was not working in tab 1 when Numberinput was >0.

What I was saying that I can't reproduce the error. Could you pls test your code again? Or maybe I'm missing smth.

In tab 1 if you set the numeric input above 0 does the print(data) line of code activate in the editor window? It works for tab 2 but not tab 1. I wrote 'print(data)' to check that the callback function is working. It is working for tab 2 but not tab 1.

Here is what I see in the browser: https://postimg.cc/0zs4Qzk3 Is this what you expected?

That is the layout i got in my original code. My question is specifically relating to the Numricinput boxes above each table and whether they are working. The callback function is working for table 2 in tab 2 but not table 1 in tab 1. I will run your edited code tonight but i just want to be sure that the problem is fully understood. I have added print('CALLBACK WORKING!') also to the callback.

That would be great, thanks. I don't see where updateTableTest is connected to the interface.

The problem that you have duplicated ids in the layout. And single callback can't be linked to two objects with the same ids:
Fix 1 - remove duplicated ids
# layout.py
def update_page(arg1, arg2):

    layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.H1(f'Class {arg1}'),
        daq.NumericInput(
            id=f"numericinput{arg1}",
            min=0,
            max=100,
            value=0, ), 
        html.Br(),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id=f"tableTest{arg1}",
            data=arg2.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in arg2.columns]),
    ])

    return layout

Fix 2 - make two callbacks, one for each table
# layout.py
def create_callback(i):

    @callback(
        Output(f'tableTest{i}', 'data'),
        Input(f'numericinput{i}', 'value'),
        State(f'tableTest{i}', 'data'),
    )
    def updateTableTest(x, data):

        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(x)
        if x > 0:
            print(data) # Indicator that shows callback is working

            return data.to_dict('records')
        return data.to_dict('records')      
    
    return updateTableTest

Fix 3 - initiate callbacks
# tab_page.py
...
# initiate callbacks:
app.layout = [layout]

lay.create_callback(1)
lay.create_callback(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
...


Thank you for this it works, is it easy to add these tables together? I know how to create a new tab called 'Total'. Is it something simple as get_layout(1) + get_layout(2).

My advise would be to stick to the methods that you are using. Slightly update get_layout. For example get_layout(0) simply won't apply any filtering when calling de.dataExtraction and thus would sum up all the data.
